# How to Rename a Folder using Batch-Processing in Windows?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I am new to Batch programming and use MacBook to code, thus unable to run this piece of code that is supposed to rename a folder.

Can anyone help me to know If it renames a folder successfully or not ? If not, give possible solutions.

```
@echo off
echo Rename a Folder
set /p ON=Name of the folder to rename:
set /p NN=New folder name:
ren %ON% %NN%
echo a folder has been renamed
pause
```

Comment: Use virtualization or look around google, many examples can be found

Comment: I have checked your code, however as I do not know what the input is I cannot say if it is correct. For instance if one of the input folder names is `My Documents` it is wrong!

Comment: Use [vmware](https://www.vmware.com/) or [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and Install desired Windows platform. Then Run your Code. That will help you a lot during programming.

Comment: Tip: get used to always put folder/file names in doublequotes to avoid problems with spaces and other "special" chars: `ren "%ON%" "%NN%"`

Comment: To add some candy:  `ren "%ON%" "%NN%" && echo folder renamed || echo rename failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your script better by using doublequotes and checking the input to reduce potential issues.

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo Rename a folder

:OldName
ClS
Set "ON="
Set /P "ON=Name of the folder to rename: "
If Not "%ON%"=="" (If Exist "%ON%\" (GoTo NewName
    ) Else Echo The folder was not found)
Echo Please try again!
Pause
GoTo OldName

:NewName
ClS
Set "NN="
Set /P "NN=New folder name: "
If "%ON%"=="" GoTo NewName
If Exist "%NN%\" (Echo The folder %NN% already exists
    Pause
    GoTo NewName) Else (Ren "%ON%" "%NN%" && (Echo %ON% has been renamed) || (
        Echo An error occurred renaming %ON%)
    Pause)
```

*You are asking for user input, and that user can put whatever they want into that input prompt. The only way to make this robust is to ensure that you fully cater for any possible input!*